# Relation between Laplace and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fractional-calculus

I have a function that has the property $\tilde f(s) = \tilde{f}(abs(s))$.

For this function, I need the inverse Fourier transform. I actually know the inverse Laplace transform of $\tilde f$ and I would like to know, whether there exists some property that relates the inverse Fourier transform to the inverse Laplace transform. I have the hope, that in this case there might exist something, since my $\tilde f$ only depends on the absolute value of $s$.

Let me be a bit more precise: Consider 
\begin{align}
\tilde f(s) = \frac{1}{|s|^\alpha+1}.
\end{align}
Then the inverse Laplace transform is given in terms of the Mittag-Leffler function, i.e.
\begin{align}
f(t) = t^{\alpha-1}E_{\alpha,\alpha}(-t^\alpha)
\end{align}
However, I need the inverse Fourier transform.
The whole question is placed in the context of fractional calculus and Green's functions for fractional differential equations. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\dfrac{1}{|s|^\alpha+1}=\dfrac{1}{|s|^\alpha\left(1+\dfrac{1}{|s|^\alpha}\right)}=\dfrac{1}{|s|^\alpha}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n|s|^{-\alpha n}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n|s|^{-\alpha(n+1)}$

Comment: I think I remember a similar expression for the transform of the Mittag Leffler function, however I don't know how to inverse transform $|s|^r$. Is there a relation for this type of expression?

Comment: @sonystarmap see 311 of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions

Comment: Don't I have a problem with 311, since it assumes that the power is positive ?